# Icon path for JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, embedded-resource, imageicon

I need image icon on jframe but I dont want to give path.
I am using this

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\folder name\\1.jpg"));
```

Because every system has different path and this is the reason I can not compile this on other system(computer).
I need some way so I can set image icon through file name only. And the image is in `src` folder.

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230). Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the `Image` as an embedded resource. The new `images` folder shown here just needs to be available on the classpath

```
public class ImageApp {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Image image = null;
                try {
                  image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/1.png"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image App");
                frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed.  It seems better to place it in an explicit directory for resources.

Answer (score -1):

You can use relative path: for example, if icon is in program working directory (the same directory as program) you can just use "1.jpg", if in folder - "folderName/1.jpg".

Comment: *"You can use relative path"*  1) Very fragile.  It presumes the current directory is that of the running Jar, which is not necessarily true of a desktop app. run from an executable Jar, and *never* true of a desktop app. run using JWS. 2) This icon is likely to become an embedded-resource by time of deployment, and will not be accessible as a `File` in any case.